# Why is my PHP Google App cron job unsuccessfully accessing the page on successive requests?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cron, file-get-contents

I've created a PHP app using the Google App Engine which makes a request to a page outside of the app itself using 'file_get_contents' as a way to request the page's content.  The PHP page it accesses then updates some rows of data in a MySQL table.  When I access the external PHP page directly, the MySQL table updates properly every time, however the PHP Google App cron job appears to access the page every 2 minutes, but my MySQL table does not update.  Is the page being cached?  How do I make my PHP Google App cron task request a new version of the external page each time?

Comment: Have you looked at the logs?

Comment: I have - logs show that the request is being completed correctly with a 200 response.  Included in my logs is also a type of "success" message which it reads from the external page only after it should have written to the MySQL table

Comment: Anything in particular I should be looking for to indicate caching or otherwise?

Comment: The easiest way to test is to add a cache buster string to the URL: http://www.adopsinsider.com/ad-ops-basics/what-is-a-cache-buster-and-how-does-it-work/